# Displaying Modal After Form Submit

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, bootstrap-modal

Here is the layout of the page I am working on:
[image: Layout]

I am having an issue on getting the functionality working for the "Close Issue" actions. The "Save" issue performs a submit where the form data is parsed and the record is saved. If the data model fails validation, the form is reshown with the model errors, otherwise it redirects back to the index page. I want the "Close Issue" to do a submit as well. I want it to save the data (including a validation check) and then display a pop-up asking the user if they are sure they want to close the issue. I've tried numerous approaches but none are working. I can do a submit without any javascript/ajax intercept and get the form data, but can't get the modal to display. I can do the intercept of the submit, but I can't get all of the form data. I'm sure I am overlooking something. Here is the code:

The partial view I want displayed in the Modal:

```
    @model EDAD.ViewModels.IssueViewModel
<!--Modal Body Start-->
<div class="modal-content">
    <input name="IsValid" type="hidden" value="true" />


    <!--Modal Header Start-->
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Close Issue</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
    </div>
    <!--Modal Header End-->

    <form asp-action="ClosetheIssue" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Issue">

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="modal-body form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group row">
                Are you sure you want to close this issue? Once you close this issue you will no longer be able to make any changes to the issue.
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <input id="issueid" type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.IssueData.issueId" class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.id" />
            </div>
            <!--Modal Footer Start-->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" id="cancel" class="btn btn-default" type="button">No</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success closeissue" id="btnSubmit" data-save="modal" value="Yes">
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                &nbsp;
            </div>

        </div> <!--Modal Footer End-->
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

    });
</script>
<!--Modal Body End-->
```

Here is the code for the "Close Issue" Button (and the Form action for both the "Save Issue" and "Close Issue":

```
 <form asp-action="Edit">
    <div id="closecontent">
    <div id="modal-container3" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div id="modal-content3" class="modal-content">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" asp-route-saveClose="close" class="btn btn-success closeissue" id="btncloseissue" data-save="modal" value="Close Test">
</div>
```

Here is the code for the Edit action:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(IFormCollection collection, string saveClose)
    {
        if(saveClose is null || saveClose == "")
        {
            saveClose = "save";
        }
        
        IssueDataModel issue = new IssueDataModel();
        try
        {
            ValidateData(collection);                
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Do stuff to save the data 
                
                if (saveClose == "save") {
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData.Remove("ID");
                    TempData["ID"] = collection["IssueData.issueId"].ToString();
                    TempData.Keep();
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(CloseIssue));
                }
            }
            else
            {                    
                return View(IVM);
            }
```

Here is the CloseIssue code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CloseIssue()
{
    ViewBag.id = TempData["ID"].ToString();
    return PartialView("_CloseIssue");
}
```

I've tried variations of the following (note that these don't represent the code snippets above) but can't get the form data submitted as well as showing the modal:

```
    $('body').on('click', '.clse', function () {
    var actionUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    $.get(actionUrl).done(function (data) {
        $('#closecontent').find('#modal-content3').html(data);
    });
    $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container3');
    $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
});

    $('#closecontent').on('click', '.closeissue', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
    form.submit();
    $('.modal').show();
})

    $('#closecontent').on('click', '.relative', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
    var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
    var dataToSend = form.serialize();
    $.post(actionUrl, dataToSend).done(function (data) {
        //Some action after data is posted
       
    });
})

    $(function () {
    $('#DisplayFileContent').on('click', '.fileupload', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
        var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
        var fdata = new FormData();
        $("form input[type='text']").each(function (x, y) {
            fdata.append($(y).attr("name"), $(y).val());
        });
        $("form input[type='hidden']").each(function (x, y) {
            fdata.append($(y).attr("name"), $(y).val());
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: actionUrl,
            method: "POST",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: fdata
        }).done((response, textStatus, xhr) => {
            //Some action to show modal

        });
    })
});
```

The last one above sends some of the form's data but not all of it.

So to sum up, I need the ability to send the entire form's data on a "Close Issue" button click, and then display a confirmation dialog box once the form data is successfully saved.

**Update 11/4**

Let me clarify. I tried each of the different javascript options above to try and send the form data. The only one that partially worked was a modification of the last one. Here is what I have at this point on that modification:

```
   $(function () {
    $('#closecontent').on('click', '.closeissue', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
        var actionUrl = "/Issue/Edit/?saveClose=close"//form.attr('action');

        var fdata = new FormData();
        $("form input[type='text']").each(function (x, y) {
            fdata.append($(y).attr("name"), $(y).val());
        });
        $("form input[type='hidden']").each(function (x, y) {
            fdata.append($(y).attr("name"), $(y).val());
        });
        
        for (var pair of fdata.entries()) {
            alert(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
        }
        alert(actionUrl);
        $.ajax({
            url: actionUrl,
            method: "POST",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: fdata
        }).done((response, textStatus, xhr) => {
            //Do something
        });
    })
});
```

1. It is not setup to iterate through and determine if a checkbox is selected (It returns all of them as FALSE.
2. It does not iterate any of the Multi-select controls to show the selected items.
3. It does not iterate any dropdown controls to identify what is selected.

If I can get that working then the form data will be posted properly. I would want the multi-selects to be formatted the SAME way the FormCollection object formats them. i.e. the formcollection formats the multi-selected values like this: [Users,{L012,L013}]
I wouldn't want it to be formatted as [Users,{L012}],[Users,{L013}]

Assuming this can get worked out, the next step would be to alter what happens in the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: actionUrl,
    method: "POST",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: fdata
}).done((response, textStatus, xhr) => {
  //Do something - If model didn't validate then do NOT show _Close partial view in modal

  //Do Something - If model validates them display _close Partial in a modal
 });
```

Comment: This is my understanding.You want to post data in form(form asp-action="Edit"),and you try to use ` $('#closecontent').on('click', '.closeissue', function (e) {}` and you can pass part of form data to it,and you cannot get partial view html in $.post(actionUrl, dataToSend).done(function (data) {         //Some action after data is posted             });Is it right?If so,can you share your entire form you want to pass,so that I may know why you cannot pass the entire form's data .